# Stop Paypal from Sending Automatic Payment Subscription Emails

Tags: email, paypal

I am using paypal to handle subscriptions to my website and am concerned because PayPal emails users each month when their payment is sent. I realize this is very transparent but I see it as detrimental to my business. Other subscription services I purchase don't send me an email each month reminding me that I am paying them and how to cancel. I'm not trying to hide the fact that I am charging my users but I also don't want paypal activelty reminding them that they are paying money and giving them a link to cancel their accounts.

Does anyone know how to stop automatic emails from being sent from the merchant end or can it only be done by each individual user?

If it can't be done does anyone know of other services I can use to run my subscription billing that give me that control? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently manage 3,000+ subscriptions via PayPal and have used PayPal for subscriptions for three years. You are correct, this is for transparency. I've never seen the option to disable this, and I doubt PayPal would ever offer it. You'll learn that PayPal is much more interested in catering to buyers than sellers. They keep the buyer happy to the detriment of the seller. For example, PayPal recently reversed 7 months of subscription payments because the buyer called into PayPal and claimed it was unauthorized. We keep plenty of records to prove this isn't true, but PayPal consistently rules in the buyer's favor regardless (we have, yet, in three years to "win" a claim against us). There is very little protection for sellers of digital goods.

Depending on how you decide to run your business, the payment reminders can be used to your advantage. I often receive emails from buyers who claim that they've canceled, yet, we've charged them again, or, they claim they've been charged for months and didn't know it. Thanks to the emails from PayPal, I know, without a doubt, that they were notified each time they were charged, and that if they had actually cancelled, they wouldn't have been charged.

There are many other payment processing services like PayPal that are more "hands-off", but their rates are equal or greater. The only one I've found that's comparable is Payza. Again, there are others, but you have to weigh the benefit of full control (including being the help desk for payment issues), and higher rate, versus PayPal's practices.

Comment: Thank you @Justin. I ended up going with Stripe to process my payments. The framework they provide was simple to implement and gives me control over when my users get emailed.